# display rating stars xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

In a new xCode project i'm parsing a rating for example 3,5. But i want to display this score in my App. Not as a text but as in images like 3 filled stars and 1 halve filled star. Is there a way to do it? Yes? How i can do this?

What elements i need to work to display the stars? Could somebody help me out? 
Like in the App Store

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would be several different approaches for this, like creating a `UIView` subclass that would implement a method for filling itself with `UIImageviews` (that would represent full or half stars) depending on rating but if you want to avoid reinventing the wheel you can find several iOS components that will do the job. [Some of them can be found here](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=rating).